# need clarification in returning a string from a function

Tags: arrays, c, string, function

actually i have to copy 2 names in to 2 destination one will be displaying in the stringcopy function .other name has to return to main function and print it.this program not displaying the copied name in main function.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int i;

char  stringcopy(char a[],char b[]);
int main()
{

char a[20],b[20],r[20],f[20];
printf("enter the first array:");
fgets(a,20,stdin);
printf("enter the second array:");
fgets(b,20,stdin);
f[20]=stringcopy(a,b);
printf("the array B:%s",f);
return 0;
}
char  stringcopy(char c[20], char d[20] )
{
char e[20],f[20];
strcpy(e,d);


printf("the second array is:%s",e);

strcpy(f,c);

return f;
}
```

Comment: In order to use a programming language, you will need to **learn it** first. So, go ahead and grab some basic tutorial about the C language. And **format your code.**

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks any and all knowledge of the language being used.

Answer (score 2):

1. Declare `char e[20],f[20]` in `main`.
2. Pass `e` and `f` as additional arguments to `stringcopy`.
3. Do not return anything at the end of `stringcopy`.

Comment: Also, `c` and `d` should be declared `const` in the parameter list, since the function does not modify the data.

Comment: There's a lot of "alsos" here, just wanted to give him the minimum required to make it work...

Comment: is it possible to return the string from function stringcopy to the main.

Comment: Yes: `char* f = (char*)malloc(20); ... return f`. But you will have to free the memory pointed by `f` in the calling function (main): `char* f=stringcopy(a,b); ... free(f);`

Comment: is it possible to return f without using pointer

Comment: Technically yes, but you'll be returning the address of local variable `f` in the stack of function `stringcopy`. There is no guarantee about the contents of that memory once you are out of function `stringcopy`... So you should not be doing that!